# Trying to show an element on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, form-submit

I'm trying to show a loader.gif image when my form is submited.

My loader.gif has `display:none` in CSS, and I want to display it, when the form is submited.
I'm trying to do this using my simple code below.

It seems correct for me but it's not working.

Do you see something wrong here?

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        $('.loginbox h1 img').fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.loginform h1 img {
    float:right;
    margin:7px 0;
    display:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Login Form: <img src="img/loader.gif"/></h1>
<form name="login" action="" method="post">
    <label>
        <span>User:</span>
        <input type="text" name="user" />
    </label>

    <div class="label">
        <span>Pass:</span>
        <input type="password" name="pass" />
        <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
    </div>        
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that is because, once it is submitted, it is posting back or reloading or redirecting.

You can do this:

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents submission
        $('h1 img').fadeIn('fast'); // since you aren't using that class
        $.ajax({ ... });  // use ajax to submit the form
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem was really that!!

Comment: @OzzC, glad to have helped `;)`

Comment: But it is not possible I submit the form with php and not with jQuery ajax in an asynchronously way?

Comment: @OzzC, you can pass data like `$(this).serialize()` in `data` and put your url to `url` option.

Comment: How does `$('.loginbox')` match anything when he never uses the class in his HTML??